# Include a Boostrap modal from another Page Doesn't validate form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question have been answered so many times, **Jquery equivalent to PHP's include**

My problem is that when I load the file is like the page was already load and the validation form doesn't take any effect... if I use php include or require_once it works like a charm, the problem is that there are many pages which are Html based that I don't want to turn the whole site to PHP.

The basic: I got a Html page called whatever.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" > 
content here...

<div id="footer_holder"></div>
</div>
<!-- /.container --> 

<!-- jQuery and all JS --> 
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>... 

</body>
</html>
```

at the end I'm including a footer which contain 2 Modals:

```
<!-- Request Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="requestModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Solicita el Servicio</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form role="form" id="requestModal" action="goto..." method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">Telefono</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" placeholder="telefono de Contacto" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="textArea" class="sr-only">Textarea</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Mensaje" name="mensaje" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div id="form_request_result"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>Borrar</button>
        <button type="submit" id="myRequestButton" class="btn btn-ghost"><i class="fa fa-send"></i>Enviar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Signin Modal Not rdy yet-->

<footer id="footer_design">
  <!-- Footer Content -->
</footer>
```

Then I got a custom.js file where all the codes goes inside a load

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#footer_holder').load('footer.html');
});

some other codes... Then validate form when user fire modal

$('#requestModal').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
            err: {
            container: 'tooltip'
            },
        icon: {
            valid: 'fa fa-check',
            invalid: 'fa fa-times',
            validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
            },
        locale: 'es_ES',
        fields: {
            telefono: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            mensaje: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

So, when I open whatever.html everything goes well, the footer loads inside the page and all good, but, when user call the Modal and click the submit Button it doesn't validate... All i can think is that the page already load and the form didn't exist when the validation was fired but I don't know how to check that on java/jquery... Like I said before, if I use require_once 'footer.html' it works, I apreciate any help on this, Thanks.

Comment: Try putting the load before the `document.ready` function. It might have something to do with that.

Comment: I didn't mentioned on my question sorry, I did try that too and din't work... jQuery(function(){ jQuery('#foot.... Then document.ready....

Comment: Placing the validation code inside footer.html seems to work but is loading kind of slow and weird... I'll keep looking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have this `footer.html` load wrapped in *two* document.ready event handlers. As long as this code is running farther down on the page than the `#footer_holder` div, then both document.ready wrappers are unnecessary. They may even slow you down a bit: http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/

Since the `.load()` method accepts a callback to run after the request is complete, you'd be better off loading the content immediately and then using that callback to initialize your validation after `footer.html` been loaded.

```
jQuery('#footer_holder').load('footer.html', function() {
  $('#requestModal').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
            err: {
            container: 'tooltip'
            },
        icon: {
            valid: 'fa fa-check',
            invalid: 'fa fa-times',
            validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
            },
        locale: 'es_ES',
        fields: {
            telefono: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            mensaje: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When I read your blog I knew you had the answer, Thanks a bunch, I'm still learning and sometimes I got lost in so much code!